# How can I change one input field in the same amount I change another input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I change the value of `b` then I would like change `a` in the same amount.

That means:

If `a` is 300 and `b` is 500 then if I change `a` to 400 then `b` should be 600. And if I change `a` to 200 then `b` should be 400.

Simple, but I do not know how to do it.

```js
$(".a").change(function(){  
$(".b").val($(".b").val() +- val($(".a")); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="a" step="100" value="100">
<input type="number" class="b" value="500">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use field to hold old value:

```
<input type="text" type="number" class="a" step="100" value="100">
<input type="text" type="number" class="b" value="500">
<input type="hidden"  id="storeValue" value="100"/>
<script>
  $(".a").change(function(){        
    var oldValue=parseInt(jQuery("#storeValue").val());
    $(".b").val(parseInt($(".b").val()) + (parseInt($(".a").val())-oldValue));  
    jQuery("#storeValue").val($(".a").val());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. One additional question. Is it possible to do the following: If I add 100 to `a` then add only 50 to `b` instead of 100?

Comment: Yes its possible, you should divide (parseInt($(".a").val())-oldValue) by 2, like this :   $(".b").val(parseInt($(".b").val()) + (parseInt($(".a").val())-oldValue)/2);

Comment: Thank you! This works fine but I actually in my code it is not 50, it is 45. So I need to write oldValue)/2,22222222222.

Comment: you can divide by 100 then multyply for any value=) like this: $(".b").val(parseInt($(".b").val()) + (parseInt($(".a").val())-oldValue)/100*45);

Comment: Ah ok! I understand! Thank you very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

If you move the problem away from jQuery, try something like this:

```
var a = 200;
var b = 400;
var difference = 0;

function changeA(newValue) {
    difference = a - newValue;
    a = newValue;
    b -= difference
}

changeA(300);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Update: Was broken, fixed. Run it in the console. This isn't a fix for the jQuery version of your code, it's to highlight a simply version of the issue so you can grow as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
   $(".a").change(function(){
    
     var diff = ($('.a').val())-($('.ah').val());
     var newval1 = Number($(".b").val())+Number(diff); 
     $(".b").val(newval1);
     $('.ah').val($('.a').val()); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="a" step="100" value="100">
    <input type='hidden' class="ah" step="100" value="100">
    <input  type="number" class="b" value="500">
```

Comment: It only works when `a` is 100, otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: you need to change hidden field value initially once you cnage the input field value. You can add $('.ah').val($('.a').val()); within document ready and outside the change event. It will resoive the issue